# What encryption should I use to encrypt cookie content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, encryption

Other than the fact that you shouldn't store important information in a cookie, what encyrption method would you suggest I use to encrypt the contents of a cookie?

One key thing is that cookies can hold only so much data (I think it is 4k?), so the encryption algorithm shouldn't increase the size of the content to a point where it becomes an issue.

The cookie currently stores:

```
WebsiteId (integer value
Name      varchar(50)
Country   varchar(50)
```

Comment: Why would you want to encrypt this? Is it secret?

Comment: if the data is too important don't save it on a cookie, save it on a session and save the session id to the cookie.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz security through obscurity.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why would a user's name and country be a secret from that very same user? If you want good advice about how to encrypt something, you have to explain very clearly what it is you are trying to prevent.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I wouldn't want something changing the WebsiteId, the name/country isn't important but I put it there to give an idea of the potential size of data stored in the cookie before encryption.

Comment: Encryption doesn't prevent something from being changed. It sounds like you want a secure checksum or something like that, not encryption.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you actually want to prevent the data from being tampered with, not encrypt it. One easy way is to use an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). Basically, you have a server secret, you hash the data with the server secret, and put the hashed output in the cookie. To validate it, you remove the hash from the cookie, compute the hash of the rest of the data using the server secret, and then check it against the hash in the cookie. The data cannot be tampered with because an attacker would not be able to compute the correct hash because they do not know the server secret.

So, for example, if the data was "foo=bar&baz=qux", you would compute the secure hash of "foo=bar&baz=qux", say it's "EN0RmBxNGyo" and set the cookie to "foo=bar&baz=qux&hash=EN0RmBxNGyo". Then when you get the cookie back, you remove the hash to get "foo=bar&baz=qux" and compute the hash of that. You again get "EN0RmBxNGyo", which matches the hash in the cookie, so you accept the cookie.

If an attacker changes "foo=bar&baz=qux", the hash will not match and the cookie will be rejected. They cannot compute the hash corresponding to the changed data because they do not know the server's secret used to compute the hash.

Note that you should have a competent cryptographer review your implementation. Poorly-implemented HMACs can be vulnerable to [length-extension attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack), a fact Flickr found out [the hard way](http://vnhacker.blogspot.com/2009/09/flickrs-api-signature-forgery.html).